# How to compare 2 objects from a class

Tags: python

I have created a class called `Dog_card`. With this, I created `player_card` and `computer_card`. I am trying to compare the same attribute from both of these objects. There are more values to each than `friendliness`, but I have removed them so it is easier to test. I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'player_card' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
class Dog_card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.friendliness = ""

    def printing_card(self):
        prnt_str = "Name: %s \nIntelligence: %s" %(self.name, self.friendliness)
        return prnt_str

def printing_player_card():
    player_card = Dog_card()
    player_card.name = dogs_list_player[0]
    player_card.friendliness = random.randint(1,101)

def printing_computer_card():
    computer_card = Dog_card()
    computer_card.name = dogs_list_computer[0]

def choose_category():
    user_choice_category = input("Please choose a category: ")
        if user_choice_category not in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
            print("Please choose from the options above")
            choose_category()
        else:
            if user_choice_category == "1":
                if player_card.friendliness > computer_card.friendliness:
                    print("Player has won the round!")
                elif player_card.friendliness == computer_card.friendliness:
                    print("It is a Draw!")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you think this error means? If you understand this, chances are you already know how to solve this.

Comment: I have tried to define my card but then i get the error  IndexError: list index out of range. So i came here for help

Comment: Wait a second, that's a whole different issue now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as it's stated in the error. Basically you are trying to use `player_card` when it is not defined inside the definition of `choose_category()`. I suggest you pass the value of `player_card` to the function like the following

`def choose_category(player_card):`

or you can define it as an attribute so that it can be accessed by the methods of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize play_card before using it. Maybe you call printing_player_card in order to intnialize before, but as you don't return anything from that function, the created object and the variable player_card only lives in scope of the function. When that function finished, player_card object variable is unknown and the object is destroyed.

if you want player_card (as well as computer_card) survice its function, you need to return it an save it to a variable outside the function code.

Furthermore your function name "printing" is bad, as you don't print anything. You just initialize your object.

Maybe that's what you are aiming at.

```
class Dog_card:
    def __init__(self, name, friendliness=1):
        self.name = name
        self.friendliness = friendliness

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: %s \nIntelligence: %s" %(self.name, self.friendliness)

player_card = Dog_card(dogs_list_player[0], random.randint(1,101))
computer_card = Dog_card(dogs_list_copmuter[0])

def choose_category():
    user_choice_category = input("Please choose a category: ")
        if user_choice_category not in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
            print("Please choose from the options above")
            choose_category()
        else:
            if user_choice_category == "1":
                if player_card.friendliness > computer_card.friendliness:
                    print("Player has won the round!")
                elif player_card.friendliness == computer_card.friendliness:
                    print("It is a Draw!")
```

Comment: i have tried ur suggestion but i am getting the error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: well you need to have a list called dogs_list_player and dog_list_computer with at least one string. But those lists should have existed with your previous code as well, in case you ever called your print function, so i assumed those existing, otherwise you need to create those lists first, or initalize your Dog_cards object directly by passing a string as name, instead of refferencing to the first list object.